# ¿Cómo hacer para cambiar la celda de un item seleccionado de un tableview con un evento de tecla en un textfield?

Tags: javafx

Es la primera vez que me encuentro en una situación rara.

Tengo una tabla que tiene de items cursos y abajo poseo un `textfield` para editar una celda de una fila seleccionada de la tabla. El problema es que cuando uso el evento `setOnKeyPressed` y ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
private void eventoTxtNombreCurso(KeyEvent event) {
    String texto = txtNombreCurso.getText();
    Curso curso = tblCursos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(curso != null)
    {
        int row = tblCursos.getItems().indexOf(curso);
        curso.setNombreCurso(texto);
        tblCursos.getItems().set(row, curso);
    }
}
```

El cursor del `textfield` vuelve al inicio!!! y  cada vez que quiero escribir de nuevo me lo manda al principio.

Espero que me puedan ayudar y que haya sido claro.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que tenía otro listener que hacía algo cuando se selecciona un item de la tabla. con `textfield.isFocused()` puedo comprobar si el textbox se está escribiendo y así anulo el evento de selección de un item